# Android - Dialog inside another dialog - How to know when they both finished excuting?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-alertdialog

I am calling method ShowDialog in my activity. I have a list of names, so I will loop in this list of names, and for each name, I will get its numbers. Some names might have just a number and some others might have more. If a name has more than a number, I will show another dialog that prompts you to select the numbers you want.

When all names have only a number, it is easy, I call dialog.dismiss, then SendSMS(listOfNumbers) and finally finish():

```
ShowDialog();
SendSMS(listOfNumbers);
finish();
```

However, the problem occurs when users have multiple numbers. I can't find a way to let me know when the process finishes.

ShowDialog() method:

```
protected void ShowDialog() {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ContactsPicker.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.alert_dialog);

    final CheckBox cbE = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxEmail);
    final CheckBox cbN = (CheckBox) dialog.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxNumber);

    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String names = "";
            String names1 = "";
            String names2 = "";

            if (cbN.isChecked()) {
                //Send invitations through SMS
                //List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<String>();
                String number = "";
                List<String> usernumbers = new ArrayList<String>();

                //Fill names string to send it back
                for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
                    //number = get_Number(contactName, getApplicationContext());

                    usernumbers = getNumber(selected.get(i), getApplicationContext());

                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Usernumbers list size: "+usernumbers.size(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    if (usernumbers.size() == 1) {
                        selectedNumbers.add(usernumbers.get(0));
                    } else if (usernumbers.size() > 1) {
                        //Show select number dialog
                        dialog.hide();
                        showSelectNumberPopup(usernumbers);
                    } else {
                    }
                    //dialog.show();
                }
            }

            if (cbE.isChecked()) {
                //Send invitations through e-mail
                List<String> emails = new ArrayList<String>();
                String email = "";

                for (String contactName : selected) {
                    email = get_Email(contactName, getApplicationContext());
                    emails.add(email);
                    names2 += contactName + ",";
                }

                //showToast("Send E-mail Checked");
                sendEmail(emails);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And showSelectNumberPopup method:

```
protected void showSelectNumberPopup(List<String> usernumbers) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_select_number, null);
    // vi = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext()).inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_select_number,null);
    //View view = (View)getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_select_number, null);
    dialogLV = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_select_number);
    dialogLV.setAdapter(new SelectNumberDialogListAdapter(getApplicationContext(), usernumbers));
    dialogLV.setItemsCanFocus(false);
    dialogLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);

    dialogLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {
            String selectedFromList = (String) (dialogLV.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
            cbSelectedNumber = (CheckBox) myView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxNumber);
            if (selectedNumbers.contains(selectedFromList)) {
                selectedItemCB.setChecked(false);
                selectedNumbers.remove(selectedFromList);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed From SELECTED: " + selectedFromList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                selectedItemCB.setChecked(true);
                selectedNumbers.add(selectedFromList);
                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added To SELECTED: " + selectedFromList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ContactsPicker.this);
    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    dialog.setContentView(view);
    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"GOT IN THE SECOND POPUP",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    dialog.show();
    if (names1 != "")
        names = names1;
    else if (names2 != "")
        names = names2;
    else {
        for (String contactName : selected) {
            names += contactName + ",";
        }
    }
    names = names.substring(0, names.lastIndexOf(","));
    //Set data to send it back to PickNamesActivity
    Intent data = new Intent();
    //---set the data to pass back---
    data.setData(Uri.parse(names));
    setResult(RESULT_OK, data);
    //finish();
    //sendSMS(selectedNumbers);
    //finish();
    dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: you can use dialog.isShowing() method to check whether its visible or dismissed .

Comment: The second dialog might be called multiple times, so how is isShowing supposed to help?

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: [Use an interface](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

What might end up being easier for you is to create two (inner) Dialog classes that extend DialogFragment and call those with `new FirstDialog().show()`. Move the associated code to those dialogs. For example:

```
private class FirstDialog extends DialogFragment {


    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog, null);
        final CheckBox cbE = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxEmail);
        final CheckBox cbN = (CheckBox)view.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxNumber);

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setPositiveButton("Text here", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //Put your on click stuff here
                    }
                }).create();

    }

}

private class SecondDialog extends DialogFragment{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.alert_dialog_select_number, null);
        dialogLV = (ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.list_select_number);
        dialogLV.setAdapter(new SelectNumberDialogListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),usernumbers));
        dialogLV.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        dialogLV.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        dialogLV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> myAdapter, View myView, int myItemInt, long mylng) {

                String selectedFromList = (String) (dialogLV.getItemAtPosition(myItemInt));
                cbSelectedNumber = (CheckBox)myView.findViewById(R.id.checkBoxNumber);

                if (selectedNumbers.contains(selectedFromList)) {
                    selectedItemCB.setChecked(false);
                    selectedNumbers.remove(selectedFromList);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Removed From SELECTED: " + selectedFromList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                } else {
                    selectedItemCB.setChecked(true);
                    selectedNumbers.add(selectedFromList);
                    //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Added To SELECTED: " + selectedFromList, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
        });

        return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("Text here", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        //What happens when the button is clicked
                    }
                }).create();



    }
```

Wasn't sure what all of your code did or how your dialogs were set up, but hopefully with this base you can fit in the rest of your stuff. When you want to get something back from your second dialog, you can add an interface to it, calling a method inside of your Activity that will do whatever it needs to do. [Here's an Android Developer link to help you with that.](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)

Comment: Thanks for this. It is informative. I got a solution and I will post it later when I make sure it works 100%.